# Why logs don't get sent from Kerio Control to Kiwi Syslog Server?

Tags: event-log, kerio

Logs aren't received in Kiwi Syslog Server.

Please see config:

[image: Config Kerio]

[image: Config Kiwi]

Answer (score 1):

As the sending application and the logserver are installed on different hosts in your network I suspect that the syslog PC's firewall is blocking ingress traffic. As a first test, disable the Windows firewall on the syslog PC completely. If messages are then recorded, reenable the firewall and allow udp/514 from your network, inwards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all friends.
problem solved.
-Kiwi Application Settings input section (UDP and TCP) both must be configured.
-Log Setting Kerio. SysLog server = IP:Port
Note: Log encrypted pages don't displayed.(https)